# node.component is not a function

Tags: typescript, forms, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying out sveltekit form actions, and it keeps on giving 500 Internal Error with the title in the console: `node.component is not a function`

`src/routes/login/+page.server.js`

```
import type { Actions } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request, cookies, url }) => {
        return { success: true }
    }
};
```

`src/routes/+page.svelte`

```html
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <div class="card-body"> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a file `src/routes/login/+page.svelte` since without it the form won't be able to work. Do note that it needs to be that **exact** filename (`+page.svelte` or `+layout.svelte` respectively).

Or, if you have a `+layout.server.ts`, add an `+layout.svelte` with `<slot/>` in it

Comment: Oof. Would be good to see the framework handle that better. Without this answer, it would have taken me forever to figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this answer because I ran into this same problem, but couldn't find a missing `+page.svelte` for a form.

I had a nested `+layout.server.ts` that I was just using to serve data, but I didn't have a corresponding `+layout.svelte`.

I just put `<slot />` in this new, nested `+layout.svelte`.

Answer (score 1):

Same error, but in my case I just had named the files incorrectly. In my case, I had:

`src/blog/[slug]/page.svelte`

instead of

`src/blog/[slug]/+page.svelte` (notice the plus sign)

Which caused Svelte to ignore the file and throw the `TypeError: node.component is not a function` error. I corrected the name and now it works.